# How to use a QML Combobox to lookup data from a c++ model and insert it into another one

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, model, qml

after creating some database applications using Qt and widgets, I am exploring Quick Controls and QML. I want to mimic the use of a QComboBox mapped to a QSqlRelationalTableModel to populate one table out of another one. Something similar to:

```
ui->cmbArea->setModel(model->relationModel(areaIdx));
ui->cmbArea->setModelColumn(model->relationModel(areaIdx)->fieldIndex("description"));
mapper->addMapping(ui->cmbArea, areaIdx);
```

(Using widgets, cmbArea is a QComboBox, model is a QSqlRelationalTableModel, and mapper a QDataWidgetMapper)

I managed to get something working like:

```
property ModeloCodificador modeloCodificador: ModeloCodificador{}
property ModeloTabla modeloTabla: ModeloTabla{}

ComboBox {
    model: modeloCodificador
    textRole: "elemento"
    valueRole: "id"
    Component.onCompleted: {
          currentIndex = find(modeloTabla.get(0, modeloTabla.codigoIdx), Qt.MatchExactly)
    }
    onActivated: {
          modeloTabla.set(0, modeloTabla.codigoIdx, currentValue)
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What's your definition of "better"?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure... Like there was another component, or best practice, while my approach was cosmetic. I mean something like a QML QDataWidgetMapper equivalent...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671679/qml-equivalent-of-qdatawidgetmapper) help?

Comment: @Jar Yes, I see your point. I will have to do something similar for the mapping. Just wanting to know if there was another "better" established way. Sorry new to QML.